# Inserting a hash before a directory name with Apache mod_rewrite or PHP?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that is like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/client/project/subdirectory/value/
```

I would like like a simple way to be able to change/redirect the URL to the following:

```
http://www.example.com/client/project/#/subdirectory/value/
```

Once the redirect is complete, the hash needs to be accessible via JavaScript. I'm okay with a full refresh/redirect, just ideally that I write this once and don't have to change it again.

In other words, when the site goes live, the URLs will be structured differently, so that:

```
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/value/
```

Will change to:

```
http://www.example.com/#/subdirectory/value/
```

**Edit:**

I have tried using this:
     RewriteRule    ^profile/?$   #/profile/   [    NC,L]

Which doesn't seem to do anything

Also tried this:
    RewriteRule    ^profile/?$   /#/profile/   [NC,L]

Which takes me to the root directory

Also tried this:
    RewriteRule    ^profile/?$   #/profile/   [R,NC,L]

Which adds the whole root path to the server, followed by /%23/profile/

Comment: I edited the question with what I tried. I'm open to non mod_rewrite solutions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a URL like the following:

```
http://localhost/tests/redir/subdirectory/value/
```

And you want to get it redirected to:

```
http://localhost/tests/redir/#/subdirectory/value/
```

Place a `.htaccess` file into the directory of `tests/redir` with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tests/redir
RewriteRule ^(.*/)$ #/$1 [R,L,NE]
```

And you will get the wanted redirect. The `R` flag plays together with the `RewriteBase` directive. Also the `NE` flag is necessary so that you can put `#` literally into the redirect URI.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I'm looking for. I had to modify it so it only did the redirect for a certain directory, and passed along all subdirectories (RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ #/profile/$1 [R,L,NE]) but this is perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The hash is already used by page anchor tags. You might need to replace it with an entity or pick a better character.